# Problems understanding ancient greek geometric Proof of the sympthom of a parabola. (probably trivial geometry)

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, math-history

This proof appears on [DIOCLES, On Burning Mirrors by Toomer, G. J](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642809835) p.10

The proof starts in the paragraph starting with *"To explain what i mean..."* and ends in that same page.
The only figure to pay atention to is figure 3 (the only one in the image), figures 4 and 5 are not relevant (they show the same proof for the hyperbola and ellipse)

The thing is, I follow the proof perfectly up to and after where it says $HZ=2ZF$, I don't understand where does that statement come from. Since the author does not bother to explain it I guess it's trivial but I have been staring at my screen for an hour and I just *dont see it*

Can anyone explain to me why $HZ=2ZF$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call W the point of intersection of GZ with the axis of the cone AF. Since GZ is a dimeter of a circle parallel to the circle MKN, W is the midpoint of GZ. Next, observe that the triangles ZWF and ZGH are similar (both right triangles with a common acute angle) Therefore, ZF=FH (because ZW=WG).

Comment: Thanks!, you ment $W$ the point of intersection of $GZ$ and $AF$, not $ZF$ right?

Comment: So basically since $\Delta ZWF$ is similar to $\Delta ZGH$ and $ZW$ is half of $ZG$ then $\Delta  ZGH$ is twice as big so it has twice the base.

Comment: Did it all just occurred to you or something the author says suggested this? (It totally makes sense but I could not come up with this myself)

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Sure. I will edit it.

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Just occurred to me. I have some experience solving synthetic geometry problems.

Comment: +1 for teaching me the term "synthethic geometry" c:

Comment: shouldnt $GF$ be perpendicular to $ZF$ in the figure then?

Comment: I do not think so. It depends on angular measure of the cone. I think that if the cone has a 45 degrees spread angle, that would be the case.

Comment: yeah it's a right angled cone, angle $<ZAN= 90\deg$, sorry I didnt notice that was not stated in that particular page, thank you!. I guess the figure is a bit misleading.